# Viewing an Excel worksheet in C# with Visual Studio 2019 - how to make a work sheet visible?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to open an Excel workbook and get the sheet I want by name. I can tell Excel starts because I can see it in Task Manager.

I can tell the WorkBook that I request is the correct name because I can see the proper name in the `workbook.name` code.

I can tell the WorkSheet that I request is the right name because I can see the proper name in the `worksheet.name` code.

I don't know if the WorkBook is really opening, or if it is, I don't know how to get the WorkSheet and open it.

How do I get the WorkSheet and make it visible for editing?

Additional notes: the WorkSheet is not hidden or protected in the workbook.

See the code and some things I have tried, that is now commented out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office;

private void CmdOpenDataSheets_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Range oRng;

    string currDirectorPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string strFile = "Food Pantry Registry.xlsm";

    string strPath = currDirectorPath + "\\" + strFile;
    int updateLinks = 0;
    bool readOnly = true;

    //var dataFormat = 6;
    //string password = "";
    //string writResPassword = "";
    //bool ignoreReadOnly = true;
    //string origin = "";
    //string delimiter = ",";
    //bool editable = true;
    //bool notify = true;
    //string converter = "";
    //bool addToMru = true;
    //bool local = true;
    //string corruptLoad = "";

    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

    Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath);//, updateLinks, readOnly);// dataFormat, password, writResPassword, ignoreReadOnly, origin, delimiter, editable, notify, converter, addToMru, local, corruptLoad);

    //workbook.Worksheets["Totals"].Select = true;
    //workbook.Worksheets["Totals"].Activate = true;
    //workbook.Worksheets["Totals"].Open = true;

    //bool isSelected = workbook.Worksheets["Totals"].Select;
    //bool isAtivated = workbook.Worksheets["Totals"].Activate;
    //bool isVisible = workbook.Worksheets["Totals"].Visible;

    Excel.Worksheet workSheet;
    workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Totals");
    //workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.set_Item(Visible);

    string temp = "";
    temp = workbook.Name;
    temp = workSheet.Name;
    temp = temp + "1";

    //Get the name of worksheet.
    //string strWorksheetName = worksheet.Name;
}
```

Comment: Did you try ``excelApp.Visible=true;``? I believe creating an Instance over Interop starts invisible by default (though I wasn't using Excel Interop for a while)

Comment: Do you want to actually use excel within your app, with all its formulas and charts etc, or do you just want to open an excel file and show its data in a grid?

Comment: I am committed to Excel because that is what the church uses. I have tried many things, but not sure if I tried that; I will give it a try.

Comment: Tried it an no luck.

Comment: I just tried: bool isVisiable = excelApp.Worksheets["Totals"].Visiable;  It builds ok but when it runs it gives the following error:             Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'Visiable''

Comment: You solved it I did not take your statement correctly, and miscoded it. excelApp.Visible = true; works fine.

Comment: Hi PaulaJoann, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)